# Adding two path names in VC++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

```
String^ Source = System::IO::Directory::GetCurrentDirectory()+ "\\DeleteFolder.exe\"" ;
String^ Destination = "C:\\Windows\\DeleteFolder.exe";
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> WSource = PtrToStringChars(Source);
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> WDestination = PtrToStringChars(Destination);
```

Is there any problem with the code above, i am unable to get the source path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, I've never done *managed* C++ so the below is just an educated guess.

You end the source path with `\"`. I assume to get the path to be surrounded by `"` to handle spaces etc, but as far as I can tell you're not adding one to the beginning of the path.

Also, rather than adding paths together, there's a method to do just that so you don't have to worry about slashes etc, just do:

```
String^ Source = System::IO::Path::Combine(System::IO::Directory::GetCurrentDirectory(), "DeleteFolder.exe")
```

And then just surround the source path with the `"` if they are needed as:

```
Source = "\"" + Source + "\""
```